# What does this notation mean? Double arrow with $z$ above

Tags: convolution, spline

I am reading a paper about digital filtering (for the very first time) and I found this notation (**double arrow with $z$ above**) which I do not quite understand.

Could you please give me some hint?

> Defining the inverse convolution operator $(b_1^n)^{-1}(k) \stackrel{z}{\longleftrightarrow} 1 / B_1^n(z)$, the solution is found by inverse filtering (cf. [97])

Comment: Does it make sense if it is a Z-transform? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform

Comment: indeed, it makes sense! I wasn't aware of the existence of such a transform, I thought that they were dealing with Discrete Time Fourier Transform. You can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [Z transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform). Just like Fourier transform, it turns convolutions into multiplications, so it can be used to undo convolutions.